# Como salvar checkbox no sqlite usando recyclerView - android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

Então tenho projeto que tem uma lista de checkbox que quando clicados gravariam em uma coluna no banco que itens foram marcados, até ai tudo bem. So que nao levei em consideração o tamanho da lista e ai quando fiz teste usando uma lista que usava scrollrow e os itens que subiam ficavam desmarcados, resolvi isto usando recyclerView. 
So que agora eu nao sei onde usar o metodo para atualizar checkbox para o banco, pois no meu projeto eu fazia na activity que exibia os itens com oncheckechanged, so que agora esta tudo na classe Adapter. Eu ja tenho o metodo de atualizar checkbox funcionando o problema é que eu não sei encaixar este metodo na classe adapter ou como pegar informaçoes(checboxes que foram marcados) da classe Adapter e usa-los em outra classe. 
Agradeço a atenção.

Este é o metodo para atualizar no banco de dados no caso o checbox:
Isto esta sendo usando na Activiy TarefaCheckList para exibir os itens a serem checkados:

```
            //Instancia do banco de dados
            BancoDeDados db = new BancoDeDados              

            //Objeto tarefa que será representado no checkbox
            Tarefa t = new Tarefa();

            //Metodo do banco para escolher a tarefa que sera 
            atualizado a conforme a posicao da lista
            t = db.selecionarTarefa(i);

            //Metodo que atualiza no banco, onde o numero 1 vai para coluna quando o item é checkado
            db.atualizaTarefa(new Tarefa(t.getCodigotar(), t.getCodigoCliente(), t.getNometarefa(), 1));
```

Este é o código da classe Adapter-TarefaAdapter com metodos do recyclerView:

```
                public class TarefaAdapter extends 
                            RecyclerView.Adapter {
                private Context context;
                private final ArrayList<Tarefa> tarefas;
                private SparseBooleanArray sba = new SparseBooleanArray();

                public TarefaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Tarefa> _tarefas) {
                this.context = context;
                this.tarefas = _tarefas;
                }


            //Metodos do recyclerView 
            @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tarefa, parent, false);
            NossoViewHolder holder = new NossoViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
            }


            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder _holder, final int position) {

            final NossoViewHolder holder = (NossoViewHolder) _holder;
            final Tarefa tarefa = tarefas.get(position);
            holder.bind(position);



            holder.nomeCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                int posicao = position;

                if (!sba.get(posicao, false)) {

                    holder.nomeCheck.setChecked(true);
                    sba.put(posicao, true);


                } else {
                    holder.nomeCheck.setChecked(false);
                    sba.put(posicao, false);

                }


                }

            });


            holder.nomeTarefa.setText(tarefa.getNometarefa());

            }


            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {

            if (tarefas == null) {
                return 0;

            } else {
                return tarefas.size();
            }
            }
```

O codigo da classe NossoViewHolder abaixo, esta classe esta logo abaixo da meus metodos do recyclerView:

```
                public class NossoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

                final CheckBox nomeCheck;
                final TextView nomeTarefa;


                public NossoViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);
                    nomeCheck = view.findViewById(R.id.tarefaChBox);
                    nomeTarefa = view.findViewById(R.id.nomeTarefa);


                }

                void bind(int position) {
                    if (!sba.get(position, false)) {
                    nomeCheck.setChecked(false);


                    } else {
                    nomeCheck.setChecked(true);

                    }


                }

                }
```

Comment: Você pode colocar a função dentro da classe `NossoViewHolder`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Entao so que quando instancio a classe do Banco de dados ele pede o contexto e nao aceita colocar a seguinte linha de codigo BancoDados bancoDados = new BancoDados(NossoViewHolder.this); se tiver outra forma, por favor me avise.

Comment: Se possível poste clique em [edit] e poste o conteúdo da classe `NossoViewHolder`. Quando você passa a *view* (no método `onCreateViewHolder`), você — automaticamente — está passando o contexto. Você também pode passar o contexto da seguinte forma: `new NossoViewHolder(view, view.getContext());`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, conforme pedido coloquei o codigo da classe NossoVIewHolder, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @ValdeirPsr nao esquece de mim! Blz?

Comment: Emerson, fiz um exemplo bem básico que você poderá seguir: https://hastebin.com/ezokuqutop.java

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, valeu muito vou analisa-lo e adapta-lo pelo exemplo que vc me passou! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!